# ColdFusion extract values from text file

Tags: regex, coldfusion, extract, text-parsing, text-extraction

**The technical details**

I want to EXTRACT values from a text file containing parameter names and values. For each line that starts with "request.config." (there are empty lines, lines with comments, etc. which I don't want to extract anything from) I want to extract these values (in bold) :

request.config.**my_param_1** = **"some random string"**;

I thought the best way to do this might be using REGEX, but how can I do this?

I thought there would be something like a regular expression that would extract the 2 values  `request.config.${1} = ${2};` and retrieve ${1} and ${2}, for each line, but only if it matches.

I tried experimenting but it did not work:

```
<cfset str = "request.config.MY_PARAM_NAME = 'The parameter VALUE!!';">
<cfset arrSearch = rematch("^request.config.(.*?) = (.*?);$", str) >
<cfdump var="#arrSearch#" label="Extracted values">
```

Unfortunately, this code gives me the FULL STRING I already had, **I just want the 2 extracted values**!

**Some META : WHAT I'm trying to do**

I am building a web app that lets end-users modify some application parameters which are stored in a params_file.cfm. Instead of having developpers change the variables manually in the file, we want to be able to do it from within the application.

My application first makes an AJAX call to the backend, which reads the params file, get all the data pairs (param_name, param_value and possibly later on a param_description) and returns them as JSON to populate my list for which I have an autocomplete tool to search them by name (Typeahead.js for the curious). When I select a parameter name the value appears along with some controls to modify them (the controls depend on the data type, JQuery is used to determine the type).

The thing is the param_value can take many forms.. because this params file is maintained by different people it can have different syntax. For example a boolean can be stored as "TRUE", 'true', TRUE, true (you get the idea).

Since the SerializeJSON handles the types (booleans, numbers, strings) I thought my REGEX should return me the text WITHOUT the quotes (single or double) but I am having trouble crafting that expression.

I got

`<cfset match = REFind("^request\.config\.(\S+) = ['|""]?(.*)['|""]?;$", str, 1, "Yes")>`

and I tested it with `request.config.my_param_1 = 'MYTEST123';` and it **ONLY REMOVES THE FIRST SINGLE QUOTE**, for some reason the expression returns me `MYTEST123'` when I don't want any surrounding quote. I need HELP with my REGEX

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to ask.

Comment: _Why_ are you parsing the file instead of just including it?

Comment: If you really have a valid reason to parse this with a regex, you need to be more specific on the format - i.e. what's expected/acceptable, particularly regarding newlines/semicolons, escapes quotes, literal structs, etc.

Comment: So your file has a CF struct... why not just include the file, loop over your struct extracting the key:value pairs and putting them into their own variables as required (although I'd have to go with @PeterBoughton and ask _why_)?

Comment: I have to read it as a TEXT file which is why I won't include it, I don't want CF to execute the cf statements here, I just want to read the values I want for each lines which are the param name and the param value.

Maybe I shouldn't have used the term "parse" since I only want to "extract values", I'll try to reformat my question

Comment: I made my question much more shorter, I hope I was clearer this time.

Comment: Start by reading the file and treating the variable as a list delimeted by chr(10).  As you loop through that list, you can read each row individually.

Comment: _"I have to read it as a TEXT file"_ - yes, I get that. I'm asking WHY. [What are you trying to do?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)

Comment: Dan, that might not work - there's nothing to say that each variable is constrained to a single line, not that every line is a variable.

Comment: `.*?` is rarely a good idea. The first one should probably be `[^ =]+` but the second one could potentially (based on the currently provided information) be a number of things.

Comment: CF's native regex functionality doesn't do returning of matched groups - I have [a library](http://cfregex.net) that lets you get at them, but again it's not clear if you're taking the best approach here in general, (hence why you need to give details on the actual problem).

Comment: My previous suggestion is based on this:  For each line that starts with "request.config."  I also said it was a start, not a complete solution.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I updated the question again to give you more context. I hope it is enough but if you need more specifics just ask here

Comment: As the original question was answered, I will link my new question related to this one (I am still struggling with the quotes).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617989/cf-regex-refind-substring-without-quotes

Comment: _"My application first makes an AJAX call to the backend, which reads the params file, get all the data pairs (param_name, param_value and possibly later on a param_description) and returns them as JSON"_ - **store the data as JSON**. You can then `deserializeJson()` to do the parsing and use functions like [StructKeyArray](http://cfdocs.org/StructKeyArray) to programmatically get the keys which have been defined, etc.

Comment: +1. Seems like you are adding unnecessary complexity. Why store it in that format instead of as JSON?

Comment: I CANNOT change the format of the params file. It is already used by a huge CF application. I am looking to edit the values in the current format, not create a new (JSON) format. I repeat : ALL I want is to edit the values in the file, even if it's more complicated than just plain storing it as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `REMatch`, you want `REFind` ([docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/REFind)):

```
REFind(reg_expression, string [, start, returnsubexpressions ] )
```

`returnsubexpressions` is what you need, so...

```
<cfset str = "request.config.MY_PARAM_NAME = 'The parameter VALUE!!';">
<cfset match = REFind("^request\.config\.(\S+) = (.*);", str, 1, "Yes")>

<cfdump var="#match#">
```

`match` will be a Struct with two keys (`POS` and `LEN`), listing the positions and lengths of each sub-match.

You can then feed this information to `Mid()` and cut out the actual substrings.

Don't forget to check whether `REFind` succeeded, `ArrayLen(match.POS)` must be 3 in your case (1 overall match, two match groups, think `$0` .. `$2`).

To find all occurrences in the entire file, either

- run this function in a loop, setting `start` to `match.POS[1] + match.LEN[1]` for the next iteration
- or loop through the file in a line-by-line manner, via `<cfloop list>` with newline `Chr(10)` as delimiter or via `<cfloop array>` and `ArrayToList(file, Chr(10))`.

Comment: I updated the question description, I need help with tweaking the REGEX so that it returns the value string without the single or double quote (for bools and numbers sometimes there are no quotes, sometimes there are).

The REGEX I tweaked returns the value without the first quote, but the last quote is still there.

Comment: As the original question was answered, I will link my new question related to this one (I am still struggling with the quotes).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617989/cf-regex-refind-substring-without-quotes

Comment: @dominicbri7 BTW you can use txt2re (http://www.txt2re.com/) to build regular expressions by example. Maybe this helps you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to try out refind(), not rematch() because it returns array data that can be used to get and found subexpressions

`arrsearch = rematch("^request.config.(.*?) = (.*?);$", line)`

Just returns the whole line:
`#Mid(line,arrsearch.pos[0],arrsearch.len[0])#`

Returns the first subexpression (varname):
`#Mid(line,arrsearch.pos[1],arrsearch.len[1])#`

Returns the second subexpression (value):
`#Mid(line,arrsearch.pos[2],arrsearch.len[2])#`

Comment: As the original question was answered, I will link my new question related to this one (I am still struggling with the quotes).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23617989/cf-regex-refind-substring-without-quotes