# CF Regex REFind() substring without quotes

Tags: regex, coldfusion, text-extraction, data-extraction

My CF backend has to read through a CFM file as if it was a TEXT file to extract the names and values of different parameters, the data looks like this :

```
request.config.MY_PARAM_1 = 'ABCDEFGHI';
request.config.MY_PARAM_2 = "BlaBlaBla";
request.config.MY_PARAM_3 = TRUE;
request.config.MY_PARAM_4 = 'true';
request.config.MY_PARAM_5 = "1337";
request.config.MY_PARAM_6 = 1337;
```

As you can see, I can have STRINGS which can be SINGLE or DOUBLE quoted.

I also have BOOLEANS and NUMBERS which usually are without quotes, but that can also have (single or double).

I am "parsing" the file and extracting the values, I want to find a pattern that would return the matches like this :

request.config.***MY_PARAM_2*** = "***BlaBlaBla***";

I am VERY close to succeeding, but unfortunately the following expression cannot get rid of the closing quote.

```
<cfset match = REFind("^request\.config\.(\S+) = ['|""]?(.*)['|""]?;$", str, 1, "Yes")>
<cfset paramVal = Mid( str, match.pos[3], match.len[3] ) >
<cfdump var=#paramVal# >
```

For example, it returns `BlaBlaBla"`, it has successfully omitted the opening quote, but not the last one, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier to instead pre-pend a string to each line and then execute the code, thus populating a local structure with the values. Didn't you already ask this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean @KevinB, I do want to populate a local structure which I will SerializeJSON before sending, the problem is that with my current implementation, the result will be for example : **"\"1337\""**, since SerializeJSON thought it was a String and not a number. Getting rid of the quotes with my REGEX would fix all these annoyances and SerializeJSON would re-add the quotes KNOWING it's a string, and would not re-add quotes for the booleans and numbers

Comment: You can solve that by going over the values and coercing the values to numbers or boolean if they are numbers or boolean. I just don't like the idea of using regexp for this, it could easily break.

Comment: For example, to solve your problem, you need to have `(.*)` match up until the last matching quote/apos. That can be solved several ways, none of which are bullet proof.

Comment: Basically, define a structure, `variables.config = {};`, do a find/replace replacing `request.config` with `variables.config`, save the file to `ram://`, include, it, delete the file, then access the properties of `variables.config`. You can then iterate over those properties converting string numbers and string booleans to numbers and booleans. Of course, this introduces a place where someone could insert malicious code if you don't trust the person building this config file.

Comment: See, this is precisely why I wasn't recommending a regex solution to your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612984/coldfusion-extract-values-from-text-file) - it'll just get more and more complicated - **use a standard data-oriented format like JSON** (or ini/property files or whatever) and you can use existing tools for manipulating the data without having to worry about matching quotes.

Comment: (btw character classes don't do alternation - i.e. `['|"]` will match those three characters; you'd just do `['"]` to match the quotes.)

Answer (score 2):

From your comments, it sounds like you're saying that you want to parse two **ARBITRARY** lines. This will do it:

```
^(?:[^\n]*\n){1}request\.config.(\w+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(\w+)\2;(?:[^\n]*\n){4}request\.config.(\w+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(\w+)\5;
```

In your code, just change the two numbers in the quantifiers: `{1}` and `{4}` as they specify how many lines to skip at the top and in the middle. For line 1, for instance you would have `{0}` in the first quantifier.

The data you want is in Groups 1, 3, 4 and 5. Please see the capture groups in the lower right panel of [this demo](http://regex101.com/r/dA0pF0)

I am sure you will have no trouble building the regex in code by concatenating the pieces:

```
method Parse(x,y)
Build the regex by concatenating
^(?:[^\n]*\n){
With 
x-1
With
}request\.config.(\w+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(\w+)\2;(?:[^\n]*\n){
With
y-x
With
}request\.config.(\w+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(\w+)\5;

Then match and retrieve Groups 1, 3, 4 and 5
```

Also see this visualization which makes it quite clear.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/qNxh7PigKEK5sJej)

Comment: I want to extract the values from 2 matches, for the first example it would be : **MY_PARAM_1** and **ABCDEFGHI** but without the quotes.

And for the example #5 it would be : **MY_PARAM_5** and **1337**.

There are my requirements

Comment: @dominicbri7 Can you please explain what makes MY_PARAM_1 and MY_PARAM_5 special? Meaning, how do I know to match those and not another? Is it about the quotes? Or about their position in a list of parameters (one is the first, the other is the fifth)?

Comment: @dominicbri7 If you're saying you want specific lines 1 and 5, see the additional regex at top of my answer. If not, please explain what criteria we use to know which two lines to select. :)

Comment: I gave #1 and #5 ONLY as examples, I am looking for a single REGExpression that would return these results

Comment: @dominicbri7 I just added an expression that will let you capture two ARBITRARY lines. It's at the top of my answer.  :)

Comment: @dominicbri7 FYI Added pseudo-code to show how to build your parser of two arbitrary lines.

Comment: @dominicbri7 This is actually one of the most interesting regex questions I've seen this week. Merci champion! :)

Comment: I used your regex ***^request\.config\.(\w+)\s*=\s*(['"]?)(\w+)\2;*** and it works great! Thank you! I did not want to parse *arbitrary lines* i just gave those as examples of the output I wanted, but the expression you gave me earlier works as expected! Merci mon ami Japonais :)

Comment: @dominicbri7 Ah wonderful, glad to hear it worked. Hey mon ami, please remember to accept the answer if you think it's alright. :) Thx!