# ColdFusion modify a single line in text file

Tags: file-io, coldfusion, edit

Is there a way to edit the contents of a single line of a text file in ColdFusion?

As I understand it, I would have to read and buffer the whole text file, then re-write it line by line as-is until I find the line I have to modify, put the value I want, then continue re-writing the rest of the lines as-is.

I don't like the idea of re-writing the whole file.. I want to find a way to edit a single line, what do you propose?

**More details**

Basically I have a config file that looks like this

```
my_own.thingy.blabla1 = "true";
my_own.thingy.bla_bla = 1337;
my_own.thingy.foo_bar_baz = "what ever...";
```

And my CFC controller receives a request like "edit bla_bla to 42"

I need to

1. Read the config file into a variable
2. Find the place in the variable where `bla_bla` is defined
3. Replace the substring 1337 by 42
4. Rewrite the file with the modified variable that contains the modified file text

**I am looking for a good way to do steps 2 and 3** since #1 and #2 are trivial

**EDIT** : Somebody pointed me out to use JSON, but I have no clue how that would apply here.

Comment: _"what do you propose?"_ - just use JSON already and stop inventing unnecesary work! Think about how a file is stored: it's a series of bytes representing the characters. A "single line" does not exist, because linebreaks are just characters. If the length of any line changes, the position of all characters after it therefore changes, so your "edit a single line" makes no sense as soon as the number of characters in that line changes, all other characters would be moved/changed anyway.

Comment: " just use JSON already and stop inventing unnecesary work! "

That doesn't help me very much... care to explain please? (The rest of your comment didn't teach me anything I didn't already know)

Comment: Just read your update. As this is a structure I think @PeterBoughton is suggesting you store your configuration file in JSON format which would make perfect sense. You can then create your configuration as a structure in CF and use the SerializeJSON function to convert it to JSON to save it to the file and the DeserializeJSON function to convert it back from JSON to a CF structure to use it in your application. As it is a CF structure you can then reference it directly to update, add and remove values.

Comment: *care to explain please?* He did, on [your other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23612984/coldfusion-extract-values-from-text-file#comment36260999_23612984). If *you* control the file, you can save the data in any format you want. Parsing the contents with regex's adds unnecessary complexity. As Peter suggested, store it as JSON. Then you can load/save the properties with a line or two of code (see Andrew's comment for details).

Comment: The process you are describing is an incredibly bad idea...there are simply too many point of failure. Peter Boughton gave you a solution in another thread...use that.

Comment: The thing is I DO NOT CONTROL the Params.cfg, it is a legacy file already used in an existing application. I am building a web tool that lets the users transparently edit the parameters. I DID NOT CHOSE THE PARAMS FILE FORMAT, nor can I. I would have used JSON if I could but I have to work with the current format.

Comment: You don't control the file but you want to provide a web tool to safely let non-programmers edit it, without yourself knowing how to parse the format the file is in. So _when_ somebody enters a value that the regex you have doesn't cope with, the file gets unwittingly corrupted and the application crashes ...what's your plan then? :/

Comment: Alternatively, you replace that file with code to read from a data file (any CFML file simple enough to attempt to parse with a regex is _not_ going to be an issue to convert) and produce a simple tool to work directly with that data file without having to worry about parsing or serialization because that problem has already been solved.

Comment: It might seem like my aim is to irritate you, but it really isn't. I would _love_ to be able to say "here you go, use this" and just solve your problem, but giving you an 80% solution that is almost certain to cause issues down the line would be doing a disservice when I know that you can easily get a 100% solution by using a simple data format, like JSON, because the relevant functionality already exist.

Comment: @PeterBoughton I personally agree with almost everything you say, but I am an intern and that is what my supervisor asks me to do, the Params.cfm is normally executed once in the application scope and the only times they used to modify it was manually, which required a developper to change it after each demand of the client. We want to let the client modify the values (it's mostly true/false like HIDE_THAT_PARTICULAR_FIELD = true;) from within the interface. So we have to modify the existing params file. (once again, I wish I could have stored it as JSON, but unfortunately that's not the case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JSON is a good way to go if you are not likely to want to edit the configuration file manually, but an 'old school' .INI style config file is easier to work with if you need to be able to jump in with a text editor.

I'd suggest creating a simple component with 4 methods:
i) Read a config into a variable
ii) Get the value of a config parameter
iii) Update the value fo a config parameter
iv) Write the whole config back to the file

As others have pointed out, you are going to end up updating the whole file anyway and unless the file is huge, your application performance impact is likely to be minimal.Keeping the code simple is likely to be a much greater benefit.

Comment: There are tools that can prettify JSON for manual editing too, but yeah an ini/properties file is also a valid option.

Comment: I agree with the fact that storing it as JSON would be very simpler, but the reality is I cannot modify the format of the param file, that is the whole point of the tool I am building.

Answer (score 5):

Surely to edit a single line in a text file, when you come to "save" the file you have to rewrite the whole file anyway, however instead of writing it line by line why not read the whole file (using cffile read) into a variable, change the appropriate part of the file and then write the whole file back using cffile write.

Don't think I would recommend writing the file one line at a time to find the line you want to  edit.

Comment: It,s the **change the appropriate part of the file** that I'm having trouble with. In my variable it's seen as ONE BIG STRING containing characters between a lot of linebreaks, is there any easy way to "loop" through that variable between each linebreak ("line by line") and "modifying just that line"?

Obviously I can use things like "indexof" and "substring" and "replace" functions but I wanted to avoid this approach in favor of something "better", if there is no other way though I will use that.

Comment: Best I can think of off the top of my head is to use the list functions with the delimiter being the line break, e.g. listgetat to get the line, then change it, listdeleteat to delete it and then listinsertat to insert it back in where you want it. Then write the list (string) back to the disk.

Comment: Oh and of course you can use the list in the loop function as well to loop over it if required, e.g. if you don't know the line numbers that need editing but need to find them.

Comment: I'm thinking of using CFLOOP file="myfile" to get it line by line, then adding each line to an array, if it's the line I want to edit (using regex) I simply re-craft it in a standard format and add it to the array.
When the loop is done I join each array element with a CRLF character into a single variable and then overwrite the file.

Comment: Seriously, if this is a configuration file, do as Peter suggests and store it as JSON, otherwise you really are making a massive amount of extra work for yourself. Also if it is configuration, you should be loading it once, onApplicationStart, and storing it in the application scope.

Comment: I agree, but the reality is I cannot modify the format of the param file, that is the whole point of the tool I am building.

Comment: @dominicbri7 it is possible to head back to use Java file buffers to iterate over a file line by line, however it is still going to become more of a headache than the JSON suggestions.  Here's a post about this : http://www.bennadel.com/blog/305-coldfusion-cffile-vs-java-java-io-bufferedoutputstream.htm

Comment: @Simonatmso.net If you knew how much I wished I could simply store it as JSON, but for technical reasons the file has to stay in that format. (it is included as a normal CFM file so it has to remain in a valid, executable ColdFusion syntax) We chose to store the meta-data for the parameters as JSON but in order for the value to be executed by the application, the parameter itself need to be in that syntax.